# Passar como parâmetro um campo da tela

Tags: html, mvc

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria de uma ajuda. Sou novato nessa área e acabei assumindo um projeto em uma metodologia que ainda não conheço bem. Estou com um projeto em MVC e precisava do seguinte auxílio.

Em minha tela tenho um campo de data e gostaria de pegar o conteúdo desta data e colocar como parâmetro dentro da mesma tela em um href. É possível ?
[image: Tela HTML]

Abaixo é o campo que tenho com a data na mesma página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode usar JavaScript nesse projeto?

Comment: Sim posso utilizar.

Comment: Vamoss lá então, você tem `id` nesses campos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode ver peguei o valor inserido no campo data e coloquei como link. Do modo que fiz foi por `focusout()`, mas você pode fazer por N eventos. O que recomendo é por `keycode` e `focusout()`

Para ver o link, clique com o botão direito do mouse em [Eu sou o link](https://link) e vá em inspecionar elemento, veja que o `href="~/PostoDeServico/ImprimirEscalaPapeleteExecGeral/2020-02-14"`

```js
$("#dataInicio").focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val() != "dd/mm/aaaa"){
    var link = $(this).val()
    $(".link_date").attr("href",`${"~/PostoDeServico/ImprimirEscalaPapeleteExecGeral/"+link}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="dataInicio"><br>
<a href="" class="link_date" id="link_data_1">Eu sou o link</a><br>
<a href="" class="link_date" id="link_data_2">Eu sou o link 2</a><br>
<a href="" class="link_date" id="link_data_3">Eu sou o link 3</a>
```

No caso eu não sei como você precisa da data, mas o jeito padrão que ela vem é: 2020-02-14
Para você modificar ela do jeito que você quer faça o seguinte:

Dentro da função `focusout()` eu declarei a variável link, portanto

```
link = link.split("-")
link = link[2]+"/"+link[1]+"/"+link[0] //formato 14/02/2020
//OU -------------------->
link = link[0]+"/"+link[2]+"/"+link[1] //formato 2020/14/02
//OU -------------------->
link = link[2]+"-"+link[1]+"-"+link[0] //formato 14-02-2020
```

Bom espero ajudar, boa sorte

Comment: Ótimo, irei implementar e já retorno com a resposta. Muito obrigado por hora.

Comment: Não foi nada, que isso! Até mais

Comment: Deu certinho. Porém como eu tenho vários itens href teria que fazer um laço para mudar todos eles? No teste que fiz mudou apenas o primeiro.

Comment: Você pode fazer pela `class=""` ai todos que forem iguais vão receber o mesmo valor!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, vê se era isso que você imaginava

Comment: Conseguiu? Se sim, por favor coloque como certo, pode ser a dúvida de mais pessoas

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu sim sim.